# Active Record callbacks with has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, callback, associations, has-many

I want to run a `before_save` or `after_add` callback every time I add a child object to a parent object (has_many association). In the callback I want to set the `end_date` property on the parent (cohort) based on the `end_date` properties of all the children (courses).

```
class Cohort < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses   
  before_save :update_end_date

  def update_end_date
    self.end_date = courses.order(:end_date).last.try(:end_date)
  end
end
```

The problem I'm experiencing is that the courses are not yet persisted to the database in the `before_save` callback, so `courses.order(:end_date)` does not return the newly added course(s).

There are several workarounds I could use (e.g. using the Ruby `courses.sort_by` method or using `after_save` with `update`), but my impression is that using the Active Record `order` method, if possible, would be preferable in terms of efficiency and best practice. Is there a way to do this with Active Record in `before_save`, or what might be best practice for this? It seems like something that would come up a lot, but I'm having trouble finding solutions that work for me, so I feel like I must be thinking about it wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do an after save on the courses that may update the cohort if their end date is later than the cohorts end date. and an after destroy on the course, that tells the cohort to update its end date to correspond to the remaining courses.

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cohort
  after_save :maybe_update_cohort_end_date
  after_destroy :update_cohort_end_date

  def maybe_update_cohort_end_date
    if cohort && self.end_date > cohort.end_date
      cohort.end_date = self.end_date
      cohort.save
    end
  end

  def update_cohort_end_date
    cohort.update_end_date if cohort
  end
end

class Cohort < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses

  def update_end_date
    self.end_date = courses.order(:end_date).last.try(:end_date)
  end
end
```

This way you only make an update if the new or updated course's end date would change the the cohorts end date.  But also catches if a course is removed then check what the end date should be

Comment: This makes sense to put it in the child (course). I was kinda hoping to put the logic in the parent (cohort), because this pertains mostly to cohorts and because not all courses have cohorts. However, if there's no clean way to do it from the parent, I can certainly put it in the child. Thanks!

Comment: If course can exist without cohort, the callbacks will need to have a check for that.  Updated my answer to check if the cohort exists before attempting to update.